How to get count based on agent in multiple columns
I have data like below in a table.



CaseNum
FirstAgent
NextAgent




1234
Rama
Raja


1234
Rama
Rama


5678
Siva
Rama


5678
Siva
Krishna



My requirement is I need to output like below.



Agent
Case Count




Rama
2


Raja
1


Siva
1


Krishna
1



I need to show both firstagent and nextagent in a single column.
We should not consider duplicates if the same agent is there in first agent and next agent.
Could some on please help on this to write the query.

Why is the agent Siva counted only once?

Hi @SelVazi .Its because he worked on same ticket 5678

You can use UNION ALL or a self-join to get the two columns into one and then use SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CaseNum) GROUP BY Agent. If the CaseNum and agent columns are indexed, the entire query will only require index scans.

Here is a way to do it using UNION ALL and GROUP BY :
SELECT Agent, COUNT(DISTINCT CaseNum) AS [Case Count]
FROM (
  SELECT FirstAgent As Agent, CaseNum
  FROM mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NextAgent, CaseNum
  FROM mytable
) AS S
GROUP BY Agent

Demo here

There's no need for WHERE FirstAgent <> NextAgent. It adds extra cost for the filter operation without really removing duplicates. These will be eliminated by COUNT(DISTINCT ..)

@PanagiotisKanavos You're correct, thank you
